# Proving arbitrary intersection of closed intervals is nonempty

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, general-topology

I'm trying to prove the following statment:

Let $\{I_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha\in\Gamma}$ be a collection of closed intervals, where $\Gamma\neq\emptyset$ is an arbitrary index set, such that $I_{\alpha}\cap I_{\beta}\neq\emptyset$ for every $\alpha,\beta\in\Gamma,$ $\alpha\neq\beta.$ Then $\bigcap_{\alpha\in\Gamma}I_{\alpha}\neq\emptyset.$

My attempt is based in consider that those intervals are compact because they are closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}.$

Since intervals are compatc sets, so intersection is compact and  satisfy the property of finite intersection, which implies intersection of all intervals is nonempty.

Is this correct? Is there another way to prove this easier?
 I'd appreciate any kind of help.

Thanks in advanced!

Comment: Just wanted to point out that $I_{\alpha} \cap I_{\beta} \neq \emptyset$ does not directly imply that the collection has finite intersection property. We have to use the fact that $I_{\alpha}$ are intervals. I hope you did prove that.

Comment: Thanks for answer @Seven. I believed that I could use the finite property. How can I use the fact that $I_{\alpha}$ are intervals?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We only know that $I_\alpha$ intersects $I_\beta$ for any two indices $\alpha$ and $\beta$. To get a non-empty intersection it is necessary to show that any *finite* intersection is of $I_\alpha$ is closed, and there we have to use that we have intervals (as the sides of a triangle show: they intersect pairwise but not all three at the same time).

Denote $I_\alpha = [l_\alpha, r_\alpha]$ for every $\alpha$. Then $[l_\alpha, r_\alpha] \cap [l_\beta, r_\beta] \neq \emptyset]$ means exactly that $\max(l_\alpha, l_\beta) \le \min(r_\alpha, r_\beta)$ (draw a picture).

Use this to show that finite intersections of these intervals are also non-empty.

Then apply the fact that the family of intervals has the finite intersection property to get the full non-empty intersection.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Henno Brandsma. Your idea it's very useful! :)

Answer (score 3):

I think "closed intervals" means intervals of the form $[a,b]$. The statement is false if you include half-intervals. (Consider the collection $\{[1,\infty),[2,\infty),[3,\infty),\ldots\}$.)

Comment: Thanks a lot @angryavian!! I supposed that "closed intervals" means intervals like I  had written it. I edit the question. :)